# Close to 100k data points with RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered within for loop

Tags: python, arrays, loops, for-loop, numpy

I have a normalized data set array with 96495 rows and 5 columns. I am only interested in plotting along the first two. (the third provides a sigma value for the second column, and the others are not of concern.)

I am unable to provide the exact code or dataset as per my adviser (I am a student), I will do my best to explain my issues. If anyone needs clarification with either the data or code, I will do my best to provide helpful and accurate information.

Note:
All of the data is within the range 0 to 1 +/- a very small error on the order of e-03 above and/or below both 0 and 1.

Problem:
When testing my code over a small range:

```
rng = np.where((data[:,0]>=4172)&(data[:,0]<=4180)) # This small range works GREAT!
# This small sample is around 300 data points
....
rng = np.where((data[:,0]>=3920)&(data[:,0]<=4180)) # A slightly larger range errors out every time, over any larger range not just the one shown here
# This somewhat larger sample is around 7700 data points
....
-- here is an explanation of the code that I have been told not to post, it is a 
def function(7 different variables)
   within which the error arises... 
....
RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in double_scalars
  z = p[k] * p[k] * sinhdx * h / (u*u - 1.0) # I know for a fact that (u*u - 1) is never = 0 so that isn't the problem.
RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
  C[k] = -z * c2 # This just produces a non-zero -(z**2) so it shouldn't be a problem.
RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
  D[k] = z * (r - c1*D[k-1]) # c1 = c2 and D[k-1] = D[0] so this should worst case scenario give D[k] = 0...
....
-- Next is a for loop with if statements controlling a pseudo rolling_window --
....Two arrays are appended through this process.
-- A 3rd order polynomial and an exponential 
   equation which creates a "spline" along the data.
```

Well I can't post images of the data as of yet, however the small sample works and the larger does not...

Question:
What could be causing these types of RuntimeWarnings?

Note:
The code works over **all** ranges provided they are small enough, as in the first scenario.

Again, I am sorry if this is vague, I will update accordingly as I am able.

Thanks!

---

**Additional code explanation of code...**

```
p = np.zeros(x.size-1, dtype=np.float) # I realize float is the default
```

as the code runs through the iterations every p[i] value increases by a factor

```
p[i]+=1.0/(x[i+1]-x[i])
```

until an f value equal to zero is obtained from

```
f = np.ones(x.size, dtype=np.float)
```

---

I am really only interested in correcting the error, such that the code to work properly over the entire range, not just small selected range.

Comment: Overflow means some value is larger than fits in its type. Anyway, you should almost always compute probabilities in log-space if you want a precise and numerically stable result.

Comment: Check all the values in the line `z = p[k] * p[k] * sinhdx * h / (u*u - 1.0)`.  What are the values of `p[k]`, `sinhdx`, `h` and `u`? If the numerator is very big and `u` is close to 1, that expression could overflow.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser, The code starts off with all zero valued p[k] and progresses from there (see update). Last I checked, u ranged anywhere from 1.003 to 1.3 give or take. I'll look into that closer thanks.

Comment: @larsmans, The word probability is distracting from the point of the question, the computation for numerical stability is needless until the entire set of data can be used appropriately.

Comment: It's not. You're getting overflows, underflows and NaNs, which is bound to happen if you compute probabilities this way.

Comment: @larsmans, I will take your comments into consideration and tweak the code accordingly to see if this indeed fixes the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was solved!

The overflows and nan values were coming from the fact that a mean value was being taken over various ranges.

```
rolling_window(the range of means values was the problem)
'''    
This is not the actual code, as stated in the original 
question, I have not been allowed to publicly release it.
This code simply demonstrates the origin of the errors.
'''
for r in range(0,x.size-1):
    if ((abs(y[r])-abs(y[r-1])) >= abs(err[r])):
        rmin = r-12
        rmax = r+13
        if rmin <= 0:
            rmin = 0
        if rmax >= x.size:
            rmax = x.size
        x_temp = np.mean(x[rmin:rmax])
        y_temp = np.mean(y[rmin:rmax])
    if ((abs(y[r])-abs(y[r-1])) >= abs(err[r]*2)):
        rmin = r-5
        rmax = r+6
        if rmin <= 0:
            rmin = 0
        if rmax >= x.size:
            rmax = x.size
        x_temp = np.mean(x[rmin:rmax])
        y_temp = np.mean(y[rmin:rmax])
               ....
    x = np.append(x,x_temp)
    y = np.append(y,y_temp)
```

The fact that the difference between the r and the r-1 values was the determination for the range over which a mean was taken, allowed for the mean to vary causing the x values to no longer remain ordered.

r value examples
: .80, .67, .34, -.45, .56, .87, .87, .93,...

x value problems
: 320, 345, 434, 454, **449**, 493, 533, **520**,...

The linear progression required by the code was broken and values that should never be < 0 were now less than 0.

The solution was to change both the range and to add an additional abs()

```
for r in range(*12,x.size-12*):
    if (*abs*(abs()-abs())
```

With these changes the code now works wonderfully and can be improved to report ever more accurate results.

Thanks to [Warren Weckesser](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1217358/warren-weckesser) for the suggestion and [larsmans](https://stackoverflow.com/users/166749/larsmans) for your persistence, ideas and thoughts.